# $S_{n+1}$ not isomorphic to subgroup of $S_n \times S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I've been asked to prove that there is no injective homomorphism from $S_{n+1}$ to $S_n \times S_n$ for $n\ge4$.

This seems to me to follow from the fact that $S_{n+1}$ cannot be recognized as a direct product of two of its subgroups, essentially because it has only one normal subgroup.  Are there any ways to do this via order considerations, as this was my first impulse upon seeing the problem.

Comment: Use the simplicity of $A_n$ for $n \geq 5$.

Comment: That's the key ingredient in the proof that I already mentioned.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how that contradicts the above proof.  The initial proposition is saying that $S_{n+1} \cong H \times K$, $H,K < S_n$.  But then $H,K \triangleleft S_{n+1}$, impossible.

Comment: @user186541 I did make a mistake, but there is still a problem. A subgroup of a direct product need not itself be a direct product.

Comment: That's true.  I don't know how to proceed

Comment: @user186541: Right, but showing that $S_{n+1}$ is not a nontrivial direct product is far weaker than what you're trying to prove. More importantly, the subgroups of $G\times H$ are in general not all direct products. Instead, consider the kernel of the map $S_{n+1} \to S_n \times S_n \to S_n$ for such an embedding.

Answer (score 3):

Since $n \geq 4$, the only normal subgroups of $S_{n+1}$ are $\{(1)\}$, $A_{n+1}$ and $S_{n+1}$. This follows from the simplicity of $A_{n+1}$. Put $M=S_n \times \{(1)\}$. Then $M \lhd G:=S_n \times S_n$, with $|M|=n!$. Look at $K=M \cap S_{n+1}$. This is a normal subgroup of $S_{n+1}$, whence $K$ equals one of the three options mentioned before: 
If $K=(1)$, then $MS_{n+1}/M \cong S_{n+1}$. It follows that $(n+1)! \mid |G/M|=n!$, which is absurd.
If $K=A_{n+1}$, then $\frac{(n+1)!}{2} \mid |M|=n!$, which cannot be the case.
If $K=S_{n+1}$, then $S_{n+1} \subset M$ and we would have $(n+1)! \mid n!$, again a contradiction.